# Curl POST request for spring mvc gives 405 Method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, curl, restful-url, tomcat8

I have a SPRING 4 application. It authenticates using Spring Security Ldap authentication. All works, but when I try to do a POST request it fails giving me a **WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported.**

I am trying to do a post request using a curl command in my script which triggers the controller's POST method and upload a file.

spring-security.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />




      <security:intercept-url pattern="/info"  access="permitAll()" method="GET" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/bookings" access="isAuthenticated()" method="POST"/>

      <security:intercept-url pattern="/chartdata"    access="isAuthenticated()" method="GET" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/uploadData/*" access="isAuthenticated()" method="POST"/> <!-- Change2 -->
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"     access="isAuthenticated()" />

      <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/performLogin"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
      <access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />
    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider  user-dn-pattern="uid={0}, ou=People,o=XXX" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <ldap-server url="ldap://ldap.xxx.com/dc=xxx,dc=com" port="389" />
</beans:beans>
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadData/{type}****?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}****", headers = {"Accept=*/*","enctype=multipart/form-data"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, consumes="*/*")
public String uploadData_type( //
        @PathVariable("type") final String type, //
        @RequestParam("theDate") final String theDate, //        
        @RequestParam("data") final MultipartFile theFile //
        ) {
    String status_message = null;
    Tracking.message("Importing '%s' file: '%s'", type, theFile.getOriginalFilename());
     ..........
}
```

type,theDate and data are passed from the script once the script does the curl call.

Script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SILENT=--silent

THIS_SCRIPT=${0##*/}

FILETYPE=$1
theFile=$2
theFileName=${theFile##*/}
theDate=${theFileName##*.}

URL="http://localhost:8080/gds-report/uploadData/$FILETYPE"

msg=$(curl $SILENT -X POST  -F "data=@$theFile" -F "theDate=$theDate" -F "filename=$theFileName"  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  "$URL")
echo -n $THIS_SCRIPT: 
if [ -z "$msg" ] ; then
   echo "Results - no message received"
   exit 1
else
   echo "Results: $msg"
fi
```

I have tried 2 solutions I found on stackoverflow: 
1) editing and trying with the passing of csrf parameters in the request or changing the method type disabling csrf . But, no luck, it always gives me a 405 Error.
2) Adding this bean in my app-servlet.xml file for allowing files of large size to be uploaded.

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResover"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000000">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

I tried to debug using curl for windows and POSTMAN both give the same error. i cannot find something more about this on any documentation. Can someone please help, I think it is something very minor I am missing.

POSTMAN ERROR OUTPUT below shows a **Allow: GET** header which I do not understand why it comes up even though I request using POST method and response header has Allow:GET only.

```
Allow → GET
Cache-Control → no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language → en
Content-Length → 1090
Content-Type → text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date → Thu, 25 Feb 2016 08:54:26 GMT
Expires → 0
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options → nosniff
X-Frame-Options → DENY
X-XSS-Protection → 1; mode=block
```

NOTE: The GET requests in the Controller are successfully completed. just the POST don't work at all.Please suggest me something. Spring 4. Java 8 Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think I found the solution. The problem is with setting the csrf tokens for a POST request using curl from command line and since this is not going thorugh the spring login page, spring does not know how to append the csrf tokens and parameter to header parameter.
- The way to do it is to turn off the csrf for just this one POST request as it is a verified curl request from commmand line and not a CORS request which could create a Cross Origin Domain issue.
- So, separate out the `<http>` and `<intercept-url>` rules for this kind of REST request and turn the CSRF off using `<csrf disabled:true>` in security.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Two things which might be possible here: Your firewall rules may be blocking the post action itself, in which case you can write a new exception (or try without the firewall on to check). Another possibility is the router itself might block the request, as though the traffic is viewed as "server like behavior" which might require port forwarding exceptions be written to the router.

Comment: Tried this.. and made sure there are no such rules. No such firewall rules.. Also localhost tomcat configs do not have anything except what comes with default..

Comment: http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/#curl-post This post deals with html requests in curl but perhaps a snippet that relates that neither of us noticed.

Comment: This is not related answer at all. I am not talking about PHP, its totally different..!! We are talking about spring securtiy and authentication. Doing a POST request using spring login and mvc